How do i see this is the binary entropy?
Im reading in the Boosting book by Robert E. Schapire and Yoav Freund and have trying to do the step between 5.33 and 5.35 but i can not figure it out could someone provide a step by step solution such that i can understand which tricks one have to use? 
